# Openstack Failed to Create Instance ovs-vsctl terminating with signal 14

Tags: openstack, libvirt, microstack

Please help.

I am following the microstack tutorial and I am stuck at creating instances [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/launch-and-terminate-cloud-instances#3-launch-instances).

This is what I get in the commandline :

[openstack --insecure server create --flavor myflavor --image 20.04 --network mynetwork --key-name mykeypair --min 2 --max 2 myinstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AymzE.png)

However I am having the following errors as shown in the webui.

[Horizon Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2I91.png)

After digging in more by running `sudo systemctl status snap.microstack.* --no-pager -l`, I found that there was an error with snap.microstack.libvirtd.service terminated with signal 14 as shown below:

[snap.microstack.libvirtd.service error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONCuw.png)

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I have to create 2 group of virtual drives which the host will use /dev/sda and ceph-osd will use /dev/sdb.